# Why am I getting TypeError: unsupported operand types for -: 'float' and 'function'?

Tags: python, scipy

This is my code:

```
def concfunction(time,k):
    return 0.1*exp((-k)*(time))

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
curve_fit(concfunction,time,k,p0=[10])
```

Where I've already got arrays for time and concentration, and I want to find `k` using `curve_fit`.

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-48cc519b697a> in <module>()
----> 1 curve_fit(concfunction,time,k,p0=[10])

C:\Users\Daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, **kw)
579     # Remove full_output from kw, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
580     return_full = kw.pop('full_output', False)
--> 581     res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kw)
582     (popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier) = res
583 

C:\Users\Daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
369     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
370         args = (args,)
--> 371     shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
372     m = shape[0]
373     if n > m:

C:\Users\Daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
 18 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
 19                 output_shape=None):
---> 20     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
 21     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
 22         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

C:\Users\Daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in _general_function(params, xdata, ydata, function)
445 
446 def _general_function(params, xdata, ydata, function):
--> 447     return function(xdata, *params) - ydata
448 
449 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'function'
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this?

Comment: How does your concentration array look like? Could you post the data you use (for concentration and time)?!

Comment: Sorry no, the data set is too large for the comments box to fit! Um it's literally just two columns of numbers that I imported from a file from my computational lab coordinator.

Comment: Then click the 'edit' button below your question and add the data there; it would really help to see the data to solve your problem.

Comment: Make sure the `time` and `k` are data, arrays, not functions.

Comment: Time is a data array, k is what I'm trying to find, I have no data for k

Answer (score -1):

If we assume `concfunction` returns float then time has to by of type: function.
What imports are you using? 
How are declared time and k?
I will guess time is a function from import or declared as function.

Comment: `curve_fit` takes a function, not data.  Or am I reading its docs wrong?

Comment: I really have no idea. I'm very very new to Python and I'm literally just using the jupyter ipython notebook for data analysis following instructions my laboratory coordinator taught me. I don't understand why it does anything it does, sorry! If you're asking where the functions and stuff come from when I open a notebook I use the command %pylab inline

Comment: Not sure if that helps?